# Cart becomes empty when cancel the transaction in onestep checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

I am working on [Depoto.](https://www.depoto.com/)

In this, Cart becomes empty when cancel the payment transaction in one page checkout.
I am using IWD one page checkout. I developed this on Magento-1.9.1.1

Comment: If the awnser above doesnt work maybe try the built in one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35153341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my question.

Please `open app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

Search for

```
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();

    //this makes the cart empty (sets the quote as converted to order)
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    } 

$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

And replace this with the following.

```
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
    $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1);
}

$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```